# How to set default language for the website

Tags: multilingual, links

We have a website with two languages - en & jp. When the URL `mysite.com` is browsed, it should load jp content. Just like browsing `mysite.com/jp`, but the URL should be mysite.com

The Site structure in CMS is like this

```
My Site
|_Website
  |_Home
    |_mypage
```

I used a patch config to overwrite `SiteDefinition.config` settings like this:

**MySite_SiteDefinition.config**

```
<sitecore>            
    <sites>
      <site name="MySite" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/Home/My Site"
            startItem="/home"
            database="web"
            language="jp" 
            domain="extranet"
            ..../>
    </sites>
```

**MyLinkManager.config**

```
<sitecore>
    <linkManager>
      <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider">MySite</patch:attribute>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MySite" 
             type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" 
             addAspxExtension="false" 
             alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" 
             encodeNames="true" 
             languageEmbedding="always" 
             languageLocation="filePath" 
             lowercaseUrls="false" 
             shortenUrls="true" 
             useDisplayName="false"/>
      </providers>
    </linkManager>
  </sitecore>
```

This worked and when I browse `mysite.com`, It loads the Japanese content. However, this led to a new issue.

All the `href` in anchor tags work fine when viewing the site in jp, but in en they are incorrect.

e.g in jp it is

```
<a href="/jp/mypage"></a>
```

but in en it is

```
<a href="/en/My-Site/Home/mypage"></a>
```

Seems like, just changing the language atttribute in `SiteDefinition.config` won't be the solution.

Please advise, what should be done to fix this?

Using sc8.2u3

Comment: Try adding second site definition **after** `MySite`, call it `MySiteEn` and use same settings as for `MySite` just change language to `en`

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have two concerns here #1. Will jp be still the default site. #2 We have used the website name "MySite" in code. If MySiteEn is now added, I'm afraid where is it gonna break the site.

Comment: When a request arrives to your application, it tries to match the first site with settings from site definition. If request is for `jp` language, it matches `MySite` definition. If request is for `en` language, it doesn't match `MySite` and it uses `website` instead. That's why your `en` links are incorrect. If you used `MySite` in the code, maybe think about changing it to `site.Name.StartsWith("MySite")` or something like that.

Comment: I had similar requirements for a site, setting the default language to something else didn't do this behavior. So maybe something else is messing with it. How are you generating the URLs?

Comment: @TamerM. No custom code. @Html.Sitecore().Field(<fieldID>, item). But I am using a custom config for LinkManager that I have updated in question.

Comment: is it jp correct language or ja-jp?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber It's ja-jp.

Comment: Hi, Why your site is under Home? try having it out like: /sitecore/content/My Site

Comment: @Qwerty can you detect the language requested in your custom link manager and if it is English can you alter the url options for `languageEmbedding` as `false` and continue?

Comment: The issue is with reference. Please check the field value from where you are generating the url. There should be cross site reference in english version.